# Print the missing words and the file name - linux

Tags: linux, match, cpu-word

I have two files in the given format:

File 1:

```
India 215.0
country 165.0
Indian 163.0
s 133.0
Maoist 103.0
Nepal 89.0
group 85.0
Kathmandu 85.0
```

File 2:

```
Nepal 89.0
would 88.0
Kathmandu 85.0
rule 82.0
king 80.0
parliament 79.0
card 79.0
```

I want to print the words that are present in one file but not the other. The file in which each word is found should also be printed next to the word. For example, I want the output to be:

```
India 215.0, file 1
country 165.0, file 1
group 85.0, file 1
....
....
would 88.0, file 2
```

I tried using:

```
grep -v file1 file2
```

I get the words that are not present in `file2`, but I want the words that are present in `file1` and not `file2` and vice-versa, with their respective file names. How can I achieve this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# print out all the rows only in file2 and append filename
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a){print $0, FILENAME}' file1 file2                                                                                                                
would 88.0 file2
rule 82.0 file2
king 80.0 file2
parliament 79.0 file2
card 79.0 file2

# print all the rows only in file1 and append filename
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a){print $0, FILENAME}' file2 file1                                                                                                                
India 215.0 file1
country 165.0 file1
Indian 163.0 file1
s 133.0 file1
Maoist 103.0 file1
group 85.0 file1
```

The default field separator is space, `$1` is the first column.